# How can I use the GROUP BY SQL clause with no aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to use the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT [lots of columns] 
FROM Client, Customer, Document, Group
WHERE [some conditions]
GROUP BY Group.id
```

SQL Server complains that the columns I selected are not part of the GROUP BY statement nor an aggregate function. Am I using GROUP BY wrong? What should I be using instead?

Comment: It looks like your question might be "eligible" for the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. Please post some sample data and then some sample desired output. Doing this will show us exactly what you need and will most likely get you an answer.

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag, because (ironically) MySQL is the one flavour of SQL that would **not** complain about including ungrouped, unaggregated fields in a grouped query. Fernando, please do not include tags that are unrelated (let alone actively misleading) to the question you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return all single occurences of a `group by` field, together with associated field values, write a query like:

```
select group_field,
       max(other_field1),
       max(other_field2),
...
from mytable1
join mytable2 on ... 
group by group_field
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using GROUP BY incorrectly. The point of using GROUP BY is to use aggregate functions. If you have no aggregrate functions you probably want SELECT DISTINCT instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    col1,
    col2,
    -- etc
    coln
FROM Client
JOIN Customer ON ...
JOIN Document ON ...
JOIN [Group] ON ...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: What I wanted with that query was to return all single ocurrences of the "group" column, as well as some other columns that go with it. Isn't SELECT DISTINCT only applicable when I want unique combinations of all columns?

Comment: but that syntax you gave will filter only the rows in which ALL columns are the same, right? I need to filter the rows in which only one column is repeated. Can DISTINCT possibly do that?

Comment: @FernandoGobbo: But what is the server supposed to do? You haven't specified what to return for the other columns. There could potentially be many different values for each of the columns. Your query doesn't make sense in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the problem is that you have table called Group, which I believe is a reserved word in SQL. Try wrapping the Group name with ' '

Comment: The actual name is Grupo, I only translated it to English, ahahah.

Comment: @FernandoGobbo Ahh I see, then you don't have to worry about that, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by all columns you are selecting that is not in an aggregate funcion.

```
SELECT ProductName, ProductCategory, SUM(ProductAmount)
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductName, ProductCategory
```

This will give you a disticnt result of Product names and categories with the sum total of product amount in all aggregate child records for that group.